# Could anyone help me with omniORB?

Tags: java, omniorb

I am learning omniORB recently, but found very little documentation on the Internet. Could anyone show any documentation of omniORB with Java? It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [OmniORB Wiki](http://www.omniorb-support.com/omniwiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions), OmniORB supports bindings for C++ and Python.  Java is not listed.